# What do we call Things/Objects we put together to draw?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I mean like in one word, What do we call the forms/formation/pattern of (vases, books, fruits, gypsum geometrical shapes, glass, ..etc) that we put together following a particular artistic way to draw or paint mainly to create a silent nature artwork?

Comment: Are you looking for the term for individual items, or for their arrangement? Or for the pattern in which they're arranged? Or for the order with which things are arranged/composed in an art piece?

Comment: I'm looking for the term for their arrangement, like after following the right order, have everything sat in its place and under a light spot .. what can I refer to this scene to make the listener understand that this arrangement is specifically for drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we refer to both an arrangement like this and an art representation of that arrangement as a **"[still life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life)"**.

Typically it is composed of inanimate objects--classic examples are bowls of fruit, flowers, flowing fabric, etc.

Comment: Yeah, Thank You so much.